# Typo3 Extbase Extension how to implement PIWIK as Option onclick, how to implement the cleanest way, expert advises welcome

Tags: javascript, architecture, typo3, extbase

We have a Typo3 Extbase/Fluid Extension. We want to add PIWIK for usage tracking. For this we use the onclick tracking Event:

```
<f:link.action action="show" controller="Controller" arguments="{foo:foo}" onclick="javascript:_paq.push(['trackEvent', 'Home', 'superactiontext']);">xyz</f:link.action>
```

The tracking with PIWIK is optional, so some clients will use it, others not. How would you implement this? Regarding on clean code and performance?

Would you use if/else in the templates on each link? Would you let the onclick in each version and check if the option is activated in the main JS of PIWIK? How would you implement this?

In our Default Layout template we have the main PIWIK trackingcode.

```
<!-- Piwik -->
<script type="text/javascript">
var _paq = _paq || [];
_paq.push(['trackPageView']);
_paq.push(['enableLinkTracking']);
(function() {
var u=(("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https" : "http") + "://127.0.0.1/analytics/";
_paq.push(['setTrackerUrl', u+'piwik.php']);
_paq.push(['setSiteId', 1]);
var d=document, g=d.createElement('script'), s=d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; g.type='text/javascript';
g.defer=true; g.async=true; g.src=u+'piwik.js'; s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s);
})();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it has to be the `onclick`-attribute, you could move the rendering of the `onclick` attribute to a partial. Then make that partial render the attribute for customers with PIWIK, and make it render nothing for the other ones. You could even add a condition to that partial that makes it possible to switch rendering on- and off via TypoScript(-constants), so you don't need to change the code for every customer.

The other approach would be to move the onclick-code to an external JavaScript, if possible. Some information might be lost or hard to recompute if done at that point, but you can still get the URL of the clicked link.

Comment: Hi Jost. Thank you for your reply. Would you think that it is better to go the partial way or to have a own viewhelper ex. extending the existing link viewhelper? Which way would consume less performance?

Comment: The second way would surely consume less performance on the server, as it done almost completely on client side. But I think because of caching it wouldn't make a big difference anyway. If doing it on the server side, I'd use a partial - no need for PHP code, so a non-programmer could change it more easily.